# Oracle 11c realted to recyclebin

Tags: database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

why table dropped is not seen in recyclebin when login as simple user but when we login as sysdba i am able to see. I am new to oracle so please explain me the reason.

Comment: Who deleted the table? How are you querying the recyclebin? The deleted table will show in the user's recyclebin. By default, when the DBA deletes a table, it doesn't go into Recyblebin.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso thank-you for your answer but when sysdba drop a table we can directly see in recyclebin. Can you please explain me the concept

Comment: Sorry, but I'm going to refute what you wrote. When a SysDba drops a table, it WON'T go into recyclebin. But can you please answer my questions, so i'll be able to help you. You want the concept of what? How the recyclebin works? Basically, from 10g Oracle has recyclebin, which is basically a rename of your table when you drop it. Then, the database will manage how long will that table remain available, for you to recover it.